# C++ В конец динамического массива не добавляется элемент с заданным индексом

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы, выделение-памяти

Меня интересует фрагмент кода начиная с Arr222 (После второго комментария). Как мне кажется, в новый массив должны передаться значения из Arr111 + в конец массива, т.к. он на 1 элемент имеет больше, занестись значение элемента с индексом K. Но результат выполнения этой части - бесконечный вывод нулей.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
//  randomize();
    int sizeArr,i,N,K;
    cout<<"Обозначьте размер массива : ";
    cin>>sizeArr;
    cout<<"Заполнение массива псевдослучайными значениями : "<<endl;
    int *Arr = new int[sizeArr];
    for (i=0;i<sizeArr;i++)
    {
        Arr[i]=rand()%10;
        cout<<Arr[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"Действие 1 - Удаление N элементов, начиная с номера K"<<endl;
    cout<<"N = ";
    cin>>N;
    cout<<"K = ";
    cin>>K;
    // (1) создание нового динамического массива размером size - N, чтобы в него перенести только нужные нам элементы:
    int *Arr111 = new int[sizeArr-N];
    cout<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<sizeArr;i++)
    {
        if(i>=K && i<N+K)
        {
        //  cout<<" / delete element / ";
        }
        else
        {
        Arr111[i]=Arr[i];
        cout<<Arr111[i]<<"\t";
        }

    }
    sizeArr=sizeArr-N;
    //cout<<sizeArr;
    // (2) 
    sizeArr++;
    int *Arr222 = new int[sizeArr];
    cout<<endl<<"Задайте номер(индекс) элемента (K), после чего добавим его к массиву "<<endl;
    cout<<"K = "; 
    cin>>K;
    for(i=0;i<sizeArr;i++)
    {
        Arr222[i]=Arr111[i];


        if(i=K)
        {           
            Arr222[sizeArr-1]=Arr222[i];
        }
        cout<<Arr222[i];
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

И вообще, можете кратко объяснить, какой толк в таких динамических массивах, если с количеством элементов нельзя работать напрямую.

Comment: Исправьте ошибку`if(i=K)` - присвоение i значение K. И проверьте ещё раз.

Comment: ох, который раз я совершаю эту ошибку, но теперь проблема другая. Допустим у меня массив Arr2 состоит из элементов 1 7 9 перед выполнением этого цикла. Но после его выполнения (при том, что K = любому индексу какой я только не писал) результат 1 7 0 0

Comment: Есть какая-то проблема, мне кажется, с индексами Arr222, т.к. убрав условие i==k, в Arr222 не корректно переносятся элементы из Arr111

Comment: @AlexGlebe Причем, если убрать строку 'sizeArr=sizeArr-N;' и записать в Arr2 элементы Arr (просто Arr, не Arr111), то все корректно. Я не понимаю, что происходит.

Comment: *"который раз я совершаю эту ошибку"* Включили бы предупреждения...

Comment: *какой толк в таких динамических массивах* - просто вы путаете смысл "динамичности". В данном случае это всего лишь создание массива в динамической памяти, а не динамическое изменение его размера. Если хотите изменения размера - используйте `vector`...

Comment: @Harry Но ведь размер массива задается во время исполнения, а не во время компиляции, то бишь динамически.

Comment: @user7860670 Но этот размер не *изменяется* динамически, не правда ли? Я, кажется, использовал именно этот термин...

Comment: @Harry Ну так и я о том же. Раз в С++ не предусмотрено изменение размера массива после создания, соответственно вполне нормально называть динамическим массив, размер которого задается во время выполнения, а не во время компиляции. Не понятно, что вам тут не понравилось.